# How to write subquery with the any quantifier using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with using any in linq I do not know how to do it correctly.
I have to write this in linq:

```
SELECT ename, job, deptno
FROM emp
WHERE sal > ANY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT sal
    FROM emp
    WHERE deptno = 30
);
```

I write only this:

```
var min = (from emp in Emps
           where emp.Deptno == 30
           select emp.Sal
          ).Distinct();

var result = (from emp in Emps
              where min.Any() > emp.Sal
              select new
              {
                  emp.Ename
              });
```

Comment: Is this summary of your query correct? "Select all employees which have a salary greater than at least one other employee in department 30"

Comment: Why are you returning a range of minimum values?  It looks like the SQL is getting a single minimum salary for department 30.  So the min query should replace Distinct with .Min(x => x) or replace the where min.Any with min(x => x)

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes and i must use ANY operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq doesn't have an [any/some](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/some-any-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator in the way Sql Server does.

```
var salariesInTargetDepartment = Emps
    .Where(x => x.Deptno == 30)
    .Select(x => x.Sal)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList(); // the ToList is not required, but seeing you're going to be executing
               // against this query many times, it will be better to cache the results.

var matchingEmployees = Emps
    .Where(emp => salariesInTargetDepartment
        .Any(target => emp.Sal > target)
    );
```

The `where` clause in the second statement says "Only include this record if this record's `Sal` property is greater than at least one entry in the `salariesInTargetDepartment` collection."